# How do I configure Webpack to prioritise node_modules over my other dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have a symlink'd repo and i need to ensure all dependencies are brought in from *my* project first, not dependency node_modules level.

This is to avoid duplication, or errors saying that packages are missing when i know i have them at root level.

```
my-app

--pkg.json
--config
----webpack.config.js
--node_modules
----react
----draft-js
----other pkgs.


symlink-repo

--pkg.json
--config
----webpack.config.js
--node_modules
----react
----draft-js
----other pkgs.
```

in my-app's webpack config i have:

```
const mapToFolder = (dependencies, folder) =>
  dependencies.reduce((acc, dependency) => {
    return {
      [dependency]: path.resolve(`${folder}/${dependency}`),
      ...acc
    }
  }, {});
```

and then...

```
alias: {
  ...mapToFolder(['react', 'react-dom', 'draft-js'], './node_modules'),

// i also tried:

  'draft-js': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/draft-js'),

},
```

How do i make sure my-app node_modules are overruling any sub dependencies?

Comment: why do you want to "overruling" that js?

Comment: @LakiGeri  when i try to build my-app it complains that the symlink dependency is missing 'react'. It should be pulling React from my-app's node_modules. Same with just running `yarn start` on my-app, it errors saying `Can't resolve 'draft-js' in <simlink dep>`. I need to establish a heirachy of deps where there are no duplicate deps.

Comment: I mainly working with vue.js, however this problem is not react specific, so let me suggest you to check the order of the imports in the main js file. My other suggestion, that you have to share your webpack config, and the main.js file, it can be useful to helping you.